# getElementsAtEvent always give last chart value when chart is created dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, chart.js

I am creating chart dynamically.Everything works properly except click event always gives the last chart value.Because the chart variable gets override in for loop and stored the last chart context only.
Can someone suggest how to stored chart reference for click event?

```
for(i=0;i<chart.length;i++)
    {
        $("#chartCon").append("<canvas id='chart_"+i+"'  arrayType="+arrayType[i]+" filterKey="+filterKey[i]+"></canvas>")


        var ctx = document.getElementById('chart_'+i+'').getContext('2d');
        **var chart** = new Chart(ctx, chart[i]);

        document.getElementById("chart_"+i+"").onclick = function(evt)
        {   

            alert($(this).attr("id"));
            var activePoints = **chart.**getElementsAtEvent(evt);//How to stored chart reference for click event
            if(activePoints.length > 0)
                {
                    var clickedElementindex = activePoints[0]["_index"];
                    var label = chart.data.labels[clickedElementindex];
                    var value = chart.data.datasets[0].data[clickedElementindex];
                    alert("label"+label);
                }
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: your  HTML anyone who might be willing to help you out would need an [minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow/help/mcve) to troubleshoot

Comment: I got the answer.If someone needs please check https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5018

Comment: you can add the answer here on SO, and select it as the correct one.